# How can we get the aws workspace working log using javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, log-analytics-workspace

I have create aws workspace, Now I want all log when we start and stop time or how many hours we have used our workspace using javascript ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WorkSpaces.html

Comment: What have you attempted so far?  Where are you encountering challenges?

Comment: I am getting current workspace State using "workspaces.describeWorkspaces", but i want how many hours we have use that workspace like if I have select running mode autostop for 3 hours and use workspace for 1 hour then i need that log.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/WorkSpaces.html#describeWorkspaces-property

Comment: Looks like that data isn't associated with the workspace object via the API, so you will probably need to pull this data out of cloudtrail.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you for your suggestion, I think I will get that data from the lookup Events operation in cloudtrail.